# Can I set Neo4j on Docker to import CSV file on the first run, not after that?

Tags: docker, neo4j

Is there a way to set docker to make neo4j import specific CSV file import only once?

or I should do that with javascript to check if neo4j is empty then load?

Of course, doing with javascript is easy. Just wondering can I do it with docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neo4j import tool (http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) runs independently of neo4j.

**Load data when building image**

You could inherit from the neo4j base image and use `RUN /path/to/neo4j-import ...` to load your data upon image creation.

This will of course load data only once.

**Load data when running container**

To load data when you run the container you have to override the script executed to run start neo4j. See `docker_entrypoint.sh` here https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/tree/master/src/3.1

The import tool works only if the database does not exist. You could maybe catch the error when it tries to load data into an existing database to have it run only once.

Comment: Just one more point (maybe you said already). where should I put the query to specify how to build the graph database?  The import tool seems different from LOAD CSV, which I used to create nodes and relationships as I wanted. How can I do these with import tool?

Comment: The import tool is meant for one time loading into a new database. So it's different from LOAD CSV. It's a tool independent of the neo4j instance, so you can easily run it at any point in the container.

Comment: Caveat with loading data when building the image is that the **/data** volume made by Neo4j's Dockerfile has to be bound to a host directory.  Any changes to **/data** done in the container creation (i.e. RUN blah blah blah) in your Dockrfile will be discarded since the VOLUME definition is made first by Neo4j's Dockerfile.  The image's **/data** could be modified by **bin/neo4j start**, sleep 5 (!important), then "do-stuff" (i.e. echo ... | bin/cypher-shell) and finally **bin/neo4j stop** (i.e. neo4j-import isn't the only solution).  But remember **/data** has to be bound to a host directory.

Comment: To load data when running container, first by docker run configure a volume in the local or remote file system. Then you just need to add the files(s) to the configured directory https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/